# I am asked to find the minimum perimeter of a group of triangles input by the user but I find errors in my code

Tags: java, netbeans

This is a java program that calculates the perimeter of triangles and displays the triangle which has the minimum perimeter.

[The output I am supposed to get should look like this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQQ6W.png)

[The output I got is displayed in this image. I am not able to say which triangle number has the lowest perimeter. How do I do that?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTm4p.png)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Minimum_Perimeter {

    public static void main (String[]args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n;                     //No. of triangles input by the user
        double min = 1000.0;
        int order =0;
        System.out.println ("How many triangles do you have?");
        n = input.nextInt();
        float side1, side2, side3; //Sides of the triangle
        float perimeter=0;
        System.out.println ("Please, insert lengths of the sides of these  triangles (3 real numbers per line): " );

        for (int i= 1; i<=n; i++)
        {
            side1 = input.nextFloat();
            side2 = input.nextFloat();
            side3 = input.nextFloat();
            perimeter = side1 + side2 + side3;    //Calculating the perimeter

        if (perimeter < min)
           min= (double) perimeter;
        order++;
         System.out.println();

        System.out.printf("The minimum perimeter is: %.1f %n" , min);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all in terms of input your program works fine. You told to take 2 triangles input. So for three sides for each triangle in total it will be 6 inputs.

The problem is that you are giving all six input in one line and that's not a problem. After three other three will be considered for next for loop. As Scanner separates value by space and tab.

Second thing your calculation for minimum perimeter is wrong. You are checking perimeter minimum value outside for loop which will be last perimeter calculated value inside for loop. So no mater what perimeter value are calculated previously you will get the last perimeter value as the final output. So that's why your program is saying 18 as minimum output.

Put the perimeter check for minimum value inside for loop it will work.

If you want to record triangle number also then declare another variable before for loop `smallTra` which will hold the smallest triangle number. Now whenever you find that perimeter is greater then minimum then change minimum value and assign value of for loop index to `smallTra`. By this way you will have minimum perimeter and triangle number also. Something like this:

```
for (int i= 1; i<=n; i++)
{
    ...//Calculating the perimeter

    if (perimeter < min){
       ..//do whatever you want
       min= (double) perimeter;
       smallTra = i;
    }
    .. //do whatever you want
}
System.out.printf("The minimum perimeter of traingle "+smallTra+ " is: %.1f %n" , min);
```

If it does not make sense please let me know in comments.

Comment: @Madhurya Does it help?? Please let me know.

Comment: I have done it myself it works fine. If it works for you please up-vote the answer :)

Comment: You should explain *why* their minimum perimeter calculation was wrong instead of showing code indicating a fix.

Comment: I have edited the answer could you please check if its fine now??

Comment: If the answer is okay could you please remove your down-vote. I will make sure not to put directly the fix.

Comment: @SachinSarawgi I have edited my question for one last doubt...please will you be able to help me with that?

Comment: @SachinSarawgi Thank you very much I got the perfect output. I have upvoted your answer! Thanks a lot once again :")

Comment: @Madhurya could you please up-vote also. :). If I really helped you.

Comment: @SachinSarawgi yes I have up-voted. Stack Overflow has recorded my up-vote but it doesn't display it publicly because I don't have a reputation above 15. But I have up-voted :)

Comment: Okay no problem. Happy to help you.